# Как скруглить у картинки углы, но при этом оставить под ней тень?

Tags: html, css, css3, изображения

Есть картинка, у которой нужно скруглить углы, но при этом оставить тень. Сейчас подложка под картинкой со скругленными углами и с тенью, но на белом фоне и по размерам выходит за края изображения. Однако, если свойству `box-shadow` назначить прозрачный цвет, то сама тень исчезнет - как можно решить задачу?

```css
.owl-item {
  box-shadow: 0 22px 87px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  opacity: 0.3;
  border-radius: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="owl-item active center">
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: я так и не понял, что конкретно вам нужно ? Уточните, пожалуйста

Comment: изменение html-конструкции допускается?

Comment: @alexoander внизу еже есть правильные ответы, даже 2
Игорь нет, зачем - уже решили

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
.owl-item img{
 border-radius: 30px;
  box-shadow: 0 22px 87px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
```

```html
<div class="owl-item active center">
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: так у вас же белый фон подложки никуда не исчез и не изменился в размерах

Comment: так а что вам надо, дать тень картинке и скруглить??? вопрос значит не правильно задан

Comment: Посмотрите сейчас, так вам надо было?

Comment: да, только `opacity` вы зачем-то убрали

Answer (score 2):

```css
   .owl-item img {
border-radius: 30px;
box-shadow: 0 12px 17px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
opacity: 0.3;
}
```

```html
<div class="owl-item active center">
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
  </div>
</div>
```